# My animate jQuery opacity isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to animate divs with the id of 1 and 2 when they are hovered on, the text opacity decreases.
For some reason neither the text is animating nor the actual div.

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 //THIS IS HOW A FADED IN AND OUT BUTTON WORKS
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("1").mouseover(function(){
        $("1").filter(':not(:animated)').animate({opacity: ".7"});
      });
      $("1").mouseout(function(){
        $("1").animate({opacity: "1"});
      });
      $("2").mouseover(function(){
        $("2").filter(':not(:animated)').animate({opacity: ".7"});
      });
      $("2").mouseout(function(){
        $("2").animate({opacity: "1"});
      });
    });
```

Comment: Show the html,I suspect those number addressing are wrong,you need # for ids

Comment: @Sleek Should work with quotes

Comment: What is the selector `$("1")` etc, supposed to be doing? This will only work if you have an element of `<1>` in your HTML markup. Additionally, selectors shouldn't start with un-escaped numbers. If you include the HTML markup for the elements you're trying to manipulate, we can give you the proper fix.

Comment: How do I select a div with the ID of 1?

Comment: Santi, thats fy

Comment: It would be `$("#1")`

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you are missing # in the selector part.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#1").mouseover(function(){
    $("#1").filter(':not(:animated)').animate({opacity: ".7"});
  });
  $("#1").mouseout(function(){
    $("#1").animate({opacity: "1"});
  });
  $("#2").mouseover(function(){
    $("#2").filter(':not(:animated)').animate({opacity: ".7"});
  });
  $("#2").mouseout(function(){
    $("#2").animate({opacity: "1"});
  });
});
```